# Specify tag score requirement for suggest-tag-synonyms in privilege info page

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, privileges, help-center

On [the page for the “create tag synonyms” privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), which is otherwise quite thorough, the requirement that one needs to have a tag score of 5 in that tag is not mentioned. I propose that this information be added.

Comment: I *assume* that this information is not provided there in the FAQ because it is already provided on the page where you create a tag synonym, which is exactly where the FAQ leaves off. For example, [the homework tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/synonyms). Do you still think it makes sense to risk over-complicating the FAQ entry?

Comment: Well, my personal perspective is that I saw the need for a particular tag synonym (a minor enough one that I didn't want to bother MSO), so I carefully read the privilege page, and then set about working towards 2500 rep, and then found I couldn't create/suggest the synonym, which was a disappointing surprise. Knowing that I didn't have the privilege, I didn't see any reason at the time that I should visit the specific page (or maybe I did and, yes, missed the text — I don't recall).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been implemented (a long time ago, I guess - [this Wayback Machine snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20130624085258/https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) from 2013 already sports it). The page now says

> #### How do I propose or vote on tag synonyms?
>
> Users with this privilege and a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **vote** for tag synonyms.